# Is there any relationship between DBMS and File Processing System?

Tags: file, relationship, database, between

Friends I need some information regarding that is there any relationship between DBMS and File Processing System? If so then please tell me and also tell me some easy example as well as complex example if u can?

Comment: This is a very general question for this site. Why do you ask it? Can you be more specific? What is wrong with [this answer](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120221021136AA4VsMR)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between DBMS and FPS except from the fact that you can store, retrieve and manipulate the data in both the system. But due to some disadvantages like data incosistency, data redundancy FPS was deprecated and DBMS has been introduced which helps in maintaing the relationship between the data & follows ACID property as well.
Hope this answers your question ... :)